# Using AudioFormatReader in Juce to load impulse responses

Tags: c++, audio, signal-processing, juce

I am creating a convolution reverb plugin using Juce and I am having some trouble loading in the impulse response audio files.

I am using the AudioFormatReader Class. Here is the code I have implemented so far which is producing some errors:

```
std::ifstream irStream;
irStream.open("1 Halls 01 Large Hall L.wav");

AudioFormatReader(juce::InputStream irStream, const juce::String &WavAudioFormat);
```

This is just an attempt at loading one audio file, ultimately I would like many.

Here is a link to the AudioFormatReader Class documentation:

[AudioFormatReader](http://learn.juce.com/doc/classAudioFormatReader.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AudioFormat::createReaderFor](http://learn.juce.com/doc/classAudioFormat.php) for this (note that this is pure virtual function, and you'll have to use one if its derived types such as [WavAudioFormat](http://learn.juce.com/doc/classWavAudioFormat.php)) alongside [File](http://learn.juce.com/doc/classFile.php). For example...

```
File myFile ("myFile.wav");
AudioFormatReader* myFormatReader = WavAudioFormat().createReaderFor (myFile.createInputStream(), true);
```

Comment: This is producing the error 'Cannot initialise a parameter of type "juce::inputStream *' with an Ivalue of type 'const char [34]'"